# Need help implementing kittycat function in C using a function

Tags: c, file-io

Need help getting display_stream function to read from stdin in Shell. When I type './kittycat' in Shell I am getting blank when it should read from stdin. Everything else works which is for one or more arguments it reads the text files (./kittycat test.txt test2.txt) and if I put './kittycat error.txt' it will say error file not found.' I am just missing a way to read from stdin using the function display_stream. Including Screenshots of shell output vs what is expected.

```
    [enter image description here][1]#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    void display_stream(FILE *fptr);
    
    int
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int i;
    
        // if no args given, read from stdin (just like shell/cat)
        if (argc < 2)
            display_stream(stdin);
    
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    
            if (fptr == 0) {
                printf("error: file not found.");
                continue;
            }
    
            display_stream(fptr);
            fclose(fptr);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    void
    display_stream(FILE *fptr)
    {
    
        int x;
    
        /* read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF,
            which indicates the end of the file. */
        while ((x = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
            putchar(x);
    }
```

[MY output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZMM.png)
[What is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX8ad.png)

Comment: It looks OK to me. What problem are you having?

Comment: _display text from both standard input and file_ Are you supposed to ask the user for some text? That part is unclear.

Comment: You need to call `fclose(fptr)` after `display_stream(fptr)`

Comment: `"r\n"` ?? What is that newline doing in the [open-mode argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen)?

Comment: A style suggestion: rather than use the `else` to run the logic of your program, you can simply `return 1;` from within the `if` that checks the arguments passed in. This eliminates a level of indentation making the code easier to read, _and_ immediately stops execution (with a non-zero return code) to ensure nothing later gets run unintentionally.

Comment: Try `fopen( argv[i], "r\n" )` --> `fopen( argv[i], "r" )`

Comment: @ChrisDutton I feel there was a nested `if`... but in the current (looped) code form, early return may not be desirable: it may be OK to simply skip missing files. `continue` could be used for that, though.

Comment: Code was edited extensively. Originally there was a check on `argc` and a printing of usage instructions.

Comment: Your program works fine, showing the expected output you show under What is expected.  The program doesn't show the output you show under My output above.  What do you want from us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `argc` to decide if the program should read from `stdin` or should open `argv[i]` to open the file.

---

Here's the refactored [and annotated] code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display_stream(FILE *fptr);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    // if no args given, read from stdin (just like shell/cat)
    if (argc < 2)
        display_stream(stdin);

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[i], "r");

        if (fptr == 0) {
            printf("error: file not found.");
        }
        else {
            display_stream(fptr);
#if 1
            fclose(fptr);
#endif
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void
display_stream(FILE *fptr)
{

    int x;

    /* read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF,
        which indicates the end of the file. */
    while ((x = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", x);
    }

    // don't close this here -- let caller do it (e.g. stdin should _not_ be
    // closed and only caller knows whether the stream is stdin or not)
#if 0
    fclose(fptr);
#endif
}
```

---

Here's a slightly more cleaned up version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display_stream(FILE *fptr);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    // if no args given, read from stdin (just like shell/cat)
    if (argc < 2)
        display_stream(stdin);

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[i], "r");

        if (fptr == 0) {
            printf("error: file not found.");
            continue;
        }

        display_stream(fptr);
        fclose(fptr);
    }

    return 0;
}

void
display_stream(FILE *fptr)
{

    int x;

    /* read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF,
        which indicates the end of the file. */
    while ((x = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
        putchar(x);
}
```

Comment: First off thank you for the help. I tried the code above and I am still getting blanks. I updated the code above and added image links to what my output is so you can see the problem

Comment: I pretested the code [in _both_ modes] before posting. It _might_ be a [kernel] TTY driver issue. That is, you have to type `ctrl-D` to force an EOF. To see if `stdin` works, try (e.g) `./kittycat < foo.txt`. It should work just like: `./kittycat foo.txt`

Comment: @BertoRoman Try printing a newline at the end of `display_stream()`.

Comment: I did ./kittycat < foo.txt and it showed the text in that file, so I guess that means it works? I am just confused cause on the output given to use, it puts several lines of text, which I am not getting

Comment: the assignment says " The display_stream function should take a file stream as an argument and repeatedly read a character from the file and display it to standard output until the end of the file is reached. This function should be used for reading and displaying text from both standard input and from a file"

Comment: Your program is mostly compatible with [real] `cat`. Your tests `./kittycat foo.txt` and `./kittycat < foo.txt` work. The only issue is `./kittycat` (i.e. reading directly from the [linux] TTY driver layer which does _line_ buffering--it holds the line until it sees newline before releasing it). I believe the issue is [as I mentioned] related to kernel TTY driver buffering. So, do the same test with `cat` and use that as a guide. I think you should see the same behavior. Try typing one line (e.g. `hello\n` and then hit `control-D` [to force EOF].

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `fclose` out of `display_stream`, it doesn’t belong there. Place it just after the call to `display_stream`.
2. Add `display_stream(stdin)` to `main` (without `fclose` this time, `stdin` shouldn’t be closed), before or after the loop. It should just work.

It will probably copy from stdin line-by-line but that’s due to buffering outside of the program which is not that easy to disable AFAIK.

Also, `printf( "%c", x )` could be `putchar(x)`

Comment: I made your changes, but wherever I put display_stream(stdin) whether its before or after the loop, it does nothing, when I do './kittycat' or any command in the Shell it doesnt give me the '~/Assignment-1$' anymore it's just blank and when I press enter just more blanks. I have to refresh or press control-C to type commands into the Shell agian

Comment: Um... do you understand what does “stdin” mean?

Comment: not 100% but I am just trying to match the output of what is expected which should be several lines of text or just standard code not just blank

Comment: That is “standard input”. That is, the keyboard, unless you use redirection. Try typing something while the program is running; after pressing <Enter> it will repeat the line you typed.

Comment: And redirection is done like `./kittycat < foo.txt`, as Craig Estey mentioned. When running a program like that, its stdin is `foo.txt` instead of the keyboard.

Comment: omg I am dumb... I get it now, i typed line of text it copies line of text.... thanks so much got it!